# See all video layers at once in a preview/program menu - Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, adobe

I work with Adobe Premiere Pro and I am editing a wedding.  We had 5 cameras at the wedding and I am having to hide and show video layers a lot to determine the best shot for specific moments and when to fade in, etc.

I've got dual screen and I would like to be able to have all the difference layers displayed on my second screen to be able to see all camera angles as the video plays to determine which shot I want to have showing at any given time.  I need the regular "program" to be able to see what the video actually looks like LIVE.

Any way to do this in Premiere Pro?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is YES!  The specific Adobe documentation you need to read is here: https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/create-multi-camera-source-sequence.html

But the general idea is simple: given a set of clips that are all synchronized on the timeline, group them together as a single object (a multicam clip or a nested sequence), and then set your viewer's display mode from "Composite Video" to "Multicam Viewer".  The multicam viewer will show, side-by-side, the 5 clips (in a matrix) and the presently selected camera angle.  When you play the clip, you can select which angle to switch to, and when.  The first time through you don't have to be super-precise about the when, because you can always slip the edit point earlier or later in the timeline as you need.  And you can later decide "I don't want Angle 2 because somebody is photobombing from that direction, so let's cut to Angle 5 instead".  It takes a little while to get the hang of it, but it's pretty easy, once you have your clips synchronized, grouped, and displayed in Multicam View.

Comment: Is there a way to do it if all 5 clips don't line up from the start?  I've got all the clips lined up in the sequence, I'd just like to see Video 1, Video 2, Video 3, etc. live at the same time as I play through the sequence.  I'm starting to think this isn't possible.  It would be nice to be able to see all of them live though because you can then decide where you want to put fades, cuts, etc. and which video track you want to have live at any given time.  Rather than having to hide video tracks to be able to see whats under them.

Comment: They don't all have to line up from the start.  Imagine you first started camera 1, then camera 2, then shot for a while, then added camera 3.  Then camera 1 ran out of storage, then you started camera 4.  Then camera 2 ran out of storage and you started camera 5.  In that scenario, the various cameras do have some temporal relationship, and it makes sense to arrange the clips on the timeline accordingly.  But you don't have to be constrained by time.  You can scroll through 5 random clips and see them all.  But cutting won't make much sense within that framework.  Only previewing will.

Comment: Do you know what settings I need to activate to have this scenario play out?  I like that concept for previewing.  I don't really need the cutting using the framework.  Just previewing.  Every time I try to set this up, it tries to play all the videos at the same time.

Comment: You just need to get your 5 clips into a sequence, select them all, nest them, enable multicam (using in points as "sync"), then set your viewer to Multicam.  Just like the Adobe documentation says.  Just like I said above.

Comment: Basically have you a cam b cam. Etc on different layers and synced. Then follow the rest of Michael's instructions. When one camera stopped rolling it will disappear from the multicam view until it reappears on the timeline. Super easy. Just make sure not to apply any effects to the audio  in the nested multicam sequence or you'll loose waveforms in the main composition you are editing the multicam in.